# Is is possible to to determine whether two objects are equal when given one, and later given the other, without storing a deep copy of the first?

Tags: java, hash, copy, time-complexity, heap-memory

Is it possible to write a method foo(x) which does not store a deep copy of x in an instance variable, where you can write the following:

```
Object obj = giveMeSomeObject()
// giveMeSomeObject() might return an “atomic” type of object like an Integer or String,
//   or it might return a Collection, Collection of Collections, etc.

FooClass aFooObj = new FooClass();
assert(!aFooObj.foo(obj));

Object clonedObj = obj.deepCopy(); // a hypothetical method that returns a deep copy

obj = giveMeSomeObject();
assert(aFooObj.foo(obj) == obj.equals(clonedObj));
```

In practice foo(x) may be able to get away with storing the hash code of x, depending on the implementation. But in principle, hash codes are not guaranteed to be unique.

If there is a way to do this (that is, save memory and the time it takes to copy that memory), how long would that way take in comparison?

Comment: You can just keep a reference to the object, you don't need to make a deep copy. I am not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: The reason you can't just keep a reference and check for identical references is that, in the final assert statement in the code above, aFooObj.foo(obj) should return true if and only if the first instance of calling giveMeSomeObject() returns an object which is EQUAL TO (not identical to) to the object returned by the second instance of calling giveMeSomeObject(). That's what "aFooObj.foo(obj) == obj.equals(clonedObj" is asserting, in a roundabout way.

Comment: You can use a hash function with a larger output. For a good quality hash function that has an output size of n bits, the probability that two non-equal inputs hash to the same output is about 2\*\*(-n). 128 bits of output are more than enough. Java provides easy access to crypto hashes that are more than adequate for the task, but they're relatively slow. You can find source code around for faster non-cryptographic hashes that have a big enough output.